# Gradle plugin cache my .aar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an aar that another team builds for me..

The first time I build everything is fine. But when that team updates the AAR, gradle cache is still caching that old aar and although everything still builds. My android studio doesn't recognize any of the new classes that I add.

And for some reason after I clean up the entire cache. Gradle refuses to ever generate any cache ever. My entire android studio is filled with red errors. (But everything still builds)

How should I deal with this situation??

Comment: Have you tried reconfiguring build.gradle file?

Comment: @Vancent In the end I disabled cache all together and it worked =/